# How can I provide a lambda function to a visitor implementation without using templates in C++?

Tags: templates, c++11

I currently have some code along these lines:

```
namespace
{
    template <class TUseDataFunc>
    class DataOwnerCallback : public IDataOwnerCallback
    {
    public:
        DataOwnerCallback(const TUseDataFunc& useDataFunc)
        : m_UseDataFunc(useDataFunc)
        {}

        virtual void visit(Data& data) override
        {
            m_UseDataFunc(data);
        }

    private:
        const TUseDataFunc& m_UseDataFunc;
    };
}

void Processor::doProcess(DataOwner& dataOwner)
{   
    auto useDataFunc = [this](Data& data) { useData(data); };
    DataOwnerCallback<decltype(useDataFunc)> callback(useDataFunc);
    dataOwner.accept(callback);
}

void Processor::useData(Data& data)
{
    // Use the data, accessing private functionality via friendship
    data.privateFunction();
    // etc
}
```

The role of the classes here is as follows:

- `Data` objects hold results of processing done by `Processor` instances
- `Processor` objects, via friendship, call private members of `Data` objects to set processing results in `Data` objects
- The `Data` objects are owned by an instance of the `DataOwner` class which provides a function for visiting the owned data
- `DataOwnerCallback` is a private implementation detail of `Processor`

Due to the need to call private functions in `Data`, `DataOwnerCallback` cannot perform the processing directly but must defer back to the `Processor` class which invoked it (friendship cannot be granted to `DataOwnerCallback` and `IDataOwnerCallback's` interface can't be changed). This is currently done by passing a lambda to `DataOwnerCallback` which captures the `Processor's` this pointer. In order to construct a `DataOwnerCallback` with the minimum of noise I have used `decltype` to provide the required template parameter.

There are several possible alternatives to this, some of which avoid the need to template `DataOwnerCallback`:

- Take in the constructor and hold a reference to a `std::function<void (Data&)>`
- Have `Processor` implement `IDataOwnerCallback`
- Use a templated free function in the anonymous namespace to construct a `DataOwnerCallback`, inferring its template parameter from the passed `useDataFunc`.

My question is are there any other ways to call `Processor::useData` via `DataOwnerCallback` without templating `DataOwnerCallback` (with the constraints given in this question and without using the suggested alternatives above)?

Comment: So, `DataOwner::accept` takes a `IDataOwnerCallback*` for polymorphism, and this cannot be changed?

Comment: Well the only reason why `DataOwnerCallback` has to be templated is because you cannot name the type of the lambda. So instead of the lambda, you can use write a custom "function object type" that replicates what the lambda does. Essentially, a `DataOwnerCallback` that takes a `Processor&` in its ctor and stores that by reference.

Comment: [Here's a purely local solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0add25c6dfa71393). You can also [get rid of the lambda altogether](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9186ef3b655f295d).

Comment: Both interesting solutions, especially the first though I suspect the second may be clearer long term. DataOwner::accept could theoretically be changed but would be inconvenient as it's used elsewhere in situations where this isn't a problem. You're quite right that the only reason I'm using a template here is that the type of the lambda can't be named. I'm unsure whether Class<decltype(T)> is considered bad style. Looking forward to the section in the new Meyer's book on preferring lambdas to bind. I suspect that's for efficiency, but wonder whether that's true for std::function as well.